# Как правильно скопировать и изменить массив объектов в копии?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Хочу иммутабельно изменить массив объектов большой вложенности, но не знаю как
Как возможно лучше всего у объекта с id: 4 изменить isExpended на противоположный?

```
items: [
    {
      title: 'Production',
      id: 1,
      isExpended: false,
      subTasks: [
        {
          title: 'Production 1',
          id: 2,
          isExpended: false,
          subTasks: [
            {
              title: 'Production 1 - 1',
              id: 3,
              isExpended: false,
              subTasks: [],
            },
            {
              title: 'Production 1 - 2',
              id: 4,
              checked: false,
              isExpended: false,
              subTasks: [],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
```

Comment: Скопировать и изменить в копии

Comment: «иммутабельно изменить» это какой-то оксюморон.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Основы JavaScript, копия объектов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511436/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b-javascript-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Звучит как заведомо ложный путь в JS. Перефразировали бы и сказали бы создание нового объекта на основе существующего. :)